# How to resolve notfitted error on SelectKbest

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

```
#Correlation fature selection
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression
from matplotlib import pyplot

def select_features (features_train, los_icu_train, features_test):
    fs = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k='all')#configure to select all features
    fs.fit=(features_train, los_icu_train)#learn relationship from training data
    features_train_fs=fs.transform(features_train)#transform train input data
    features_test_fs=fs.transform(features_test)#trasnform test input data
    return features_train_fs, features_test_fs, fs

features_train_fs, features_test_fs , fs = select_features (features_train, los_icu_train, features_test) #features selection
for i in range (len(fs.scores_)):
    print ('Feature %d: %f' % (i, fs.scores_[i]))#score of the features
    
pyplot.bar([i for i in range(len(fs.scores_))], fs.scores_)
pyplot.show()
```

Hi all I am getting this error:

> NotFittedError: This SelectKBest instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please format your code 

Answer (score 0):

The equal sign after `fit` doesn't call the fit method. Is this expected?

```py
fs.fit=(features_train, los_icu_train)#learn relationship from training data
```

Replace it with:

```py
fs.fit(features_train, los_icu_train)#learn relationship from training data
```